# How can I block custom menu from edit and delete?

Tags: 7, routes

I have a menu import via Web Service from other Drupal site. I would like to use Menu API to import this menu but I must be sure that will be impossible to remove or edit the menu (even by site Admin)

Comment: Have you imported this with feed import module?

Comment: I checked Feeds but if I am right this module allows to import only nodes